# Webpack does not output CSS into flask folder, ends up empty

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, flask, webpack

I have a very simple webpack set up for two files. This is based off of this [video](https://django-lessons.com/lesson/lesson-34-django-and-webpack-static-files-managed-efficiently).

Here is my webpack `config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve('../flaskr/static/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css)/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: path.resolve('../css/index.css')
        })
    ]
}
```

The contents of my `index.js`

```
import '../css/index.css'
```

The contents of my `index.css` are taken from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/), these are the first 4 lines :

```
html { font-family: sans-serif; background: #eee; padding: 1rem; }
body { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; background: white; }
h1 { font-family: serif; color: #377ba8; margin: 1rem 0; }
a { color: #377ba8; }
```

My webpack output is:

```
npx webpack --config config.js 
Hash: 46ffcd1c2d4f9d03c14c
Version: webpack 4.42.1
Time: 2967ms
Built at: 04/20/2020 4:36:01 PM
                         Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
/home/castone/go/css/index.css  1.44 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
                      index.js  4.49 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = /home/castone/go/css/index.css index.js
[./src/css/index.css] 39 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/js/index.js] 25 bytes {main} [built]
    + 1 hidden module
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/css/index.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/css/index.css] 1.69 KiB {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

Here is a screenshot of my folder layout:

[image: Folder structure]

In short, there is a `flaskr` folder, and a `<project-web>` folder (covered by red pen) at the same level. The webpack is going to pack up the Js and Css files in `<project-web>` and put them into the the static folder under `flaskr`, but it seems to pick up the JS file, because in the source tab of the DevTool I see content for `static/js/index.js`, but the `static/css/index.css` file is empty.

How do I get content into that file?

Comment: It looks like the home folder being created inside the js folder is where webpack is trying to put css files. I can't figure out why though (something to do with `path.resolve...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config wants to change this:

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: path.resolve('../css/index.css')
        })
    ]
```

to

```
plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '../css/index.css'
        })
    ]
```

The `path.resolve` is saying to change the file name to the absolute path, which relative to the output path, means it adds in the whole path to the css file onto the end of the output path.